# Как спарить только несколько нужных тегов в правильном порядке BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Имеется html документ, из которого мне нужно получить текст и картинки.
Получить их по отдельности особой сложности не вызывает, но мне нужно спарсить их в естественном порядке.
То есть если последовательность:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<img>
<p></p>
```

то мне нужно спарсить их именно в такой последовательности.

Разумеется, в документе огромное количество других тегов и не такая примитивная вложенность как в примере, то есть вариант спарсить всё, а потом убрать поштучно ненужное рассматриваю как крайний.

То есть вопрос в том,
Как спарсить несколько разных тегов в том порядке, в котором они на странице?

Comment: спарсить родителя в который они вложены, а затем итерироваться внутри

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ

```
    for elem in section:
        tags = section.find_all(['p', 'img'])
        for tag in tags:
            print(tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

если структура дом элементов такая

```
<div class="class">
<p></p>
<p></p>
<img>
<p></p>
</div>
```

то можно привязаться к диву,

```
a = soup.find("div", class_="class")
```

так же из дива можешь получить отдельно элементы, если понадобятся, именно этого блока

```
b = a.find_all('p')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вы не поняли задачи